# SED expression for swapping columns

Tags: awk, sed, centos, expression

I'm trying to figure out how to swap columns1 with column2 seperated by ':' with a SED expression.

Case example:

```
column1:column2
column1:column2
column1:column2
```

I'd like to change to this:

```
column2:column1
column2:column1
column2:column1
```

I tried the following, but it just outputs it with no change.

```
sed 's/\([^ ]*\)[ ][ ^C\([^ ]*\)/\2 \1/' test.txt > test1.txt
```

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following. Using OP's attempt of back referencing here.

```
sed 's/\([^:]*\):\(.*\)/\2:\1/' Input_file
```

***2nd solution:*** In `awk` using a temporary variable and swapping values of both the fields.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {tmp=$1;$1=$2;$2=tmp} 1' Input_file
```

OR as per Sundeep's suggestion try simply printing them:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"} {print $2, $1}' Input_file
```

***Why OP's attempt is not working:*** OP's method of using back references capability is looking Good but in regex OP is looking for space to match which is not present, so we need to mention `:` as per Input_file and it should work then with little tweak.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried my best but those SED expressions are confusing and difficult. I really like how you've explained different alternatives. Appreciate it guys. btw. it worked :)